# Bitcore vs bitcoin

Tags: bitcore, insight-api

Currently bitpay has provided the complete code for the webwallet+blockchain explorer + bitcore running

can we use same thing for the bitcoin blockchain ? or the system that bitpay has developed will work only for the bitcore(BTX)

https://blog.bitpay.com/announcing-the-bitcore-wallet-suite/

Answer (score 1):

Bitpay's Bitcore is unrelated to BTX, though it shares the same name. It was built for Bitcoin (BTC) though Bitpay may or may not choose to support BTX in addition to other coins such as BCH.

See [Bitcore - A full stack for bitcoin and blockchain-based applications](https://github.com/bitpay/bitcore)

Comment: Thanks ,JBaczuk , Is this means we can use https://github.com/bitpay/bitcore for the own bitcoin application setup.  I want to setup new bitcoin wallet . So can i use this ? i will setup the complete code from the above url on my dedicated server which allow users to send and receive bitcoin and also dont want that customer data or private key store directly on my server. (running as node + webserver for web wallet+ blockchain explorer)

Comment: That is what they say you can do with it. I have never used it myself.